# Lambda - Get function start time and count concurrently running function for a single function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

For a single Lambda function x, I would like to get ( most preferably from CloudWatch metric) the start time and concurrent "running" count.

Basically all the time passed before running my code

[image]

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I think Invocations can solve your issue, you can see these metrics in CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this week. This starts to be supported by AWS

We can look into the REPORT entry inside CloudWatch Logs for Lambda and see the result

> REPORT RequestId: xxxx Duration: 857.36 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 168 MB Init Duration: 4361.00 ms

Also for Concurrent Exec, It's [now supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html) for some specific cases

> Emitted as an aggregate metric for all functions in the account, and
>   for **functions that have a custom concurrency limit specified**

Inside CloudWatch > Metrics